# Non-trivial examples of a system being a zero-knowledge proof system but not zero-knowledge proof of knowledge

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

It got me confused these days when I encountered the notions of zero-knowledge proofs (ZKP) and zero-knowledge proofs of knowledge (ZKPoK). As far as I know, the two terms are not the same, but all the ZKP systems I know so far also happen to be ZKPoK systems.

Can anyone tell me if there is any non-trivial example of a system being a zero-knowledge proof system but not zero-knowledge proof of knowledge, and vice versa?

Comment: This question is on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68785/what-is-difference-between-zero-knowledge-proof-and-zero-knowledge-proof-of-know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between Zero Knowledge proof and Zero Knowledge Proof of Knowledge?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68785/what-is-difference-between-zero-knowledge-proof-and-zero-knowledge-proof-of-know)

Comment: Not quite the same. What I ask for is a non-trivial example. Here, group membership is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

At first, every ZKPoK protocol is ZKP protocol. This is obvious: if you proved that you know a witness, therefore a witness exists, therefore the statement belongs to the language.

The interesting question is whether a protocol exists which is ZKP but not ZKPoK.
It holds for trivial languages, but you're justly not satisfied with this.
My idea in a discrete log settings, similar to Schnorr protocol, is the following:
 take a protocol proving the equality of the discrete logarithms of $y_1$, $y_2$ to 
bases $g, h \in G$,
i.e. for a language $\{ g||h||y_1||y_2 : \exists w, y_1 = g^w \land y_2 = h^w  \}$,
where $w\in Z_q$ is a witness. $G$ is cyclic group here.

The classical Schnorr-like protocol for that is the following:

1. Prover chooses $k\in Z_q$, calculates $C_1=g^k, C_2=h^k$ and sends $C_2, C_2$ to Verifier.
2. Verifier chooses $e\in Z_k$ and sends it to Prover.
3. Prover calculates $r = k + ew$ and sends it to Verifier.
4. Verifier checks: $C_1 y_1^e = g^r$ and $C_2 y_2^e = h^r$.

You can easily build knowledge extractor E which will extract $w$ (just the same as in Schnorr protocol), so this is clearly ZKPoK protocol for a language $L_1 = \{ g||h||y_1||y_2 : \exists w, y_1 = g^w \land y_2 = h^w  \}$.

But, notice that this is also a ZKP for a language $L_2 = \{ g||h||y_1||y_2 : \exists v, h = g^v \land y_2 = y_1^v \}$.
The language is actually the same ($L_1 = L_2 = L$), but it's defined through another witnesses.
And knowing a witness $w$ doesn't help you to find witness $v$.
So, this protocol is not a ZKPoK for $L_2$, while it's ZKP for it.

The trick we did here is in the following. We have a language which could be 
independently defined by two types of witnesses. You can use say the witness of the first type to provide a proof, but you could not know the witness of the second type. You can say that it's just a trick and this protocol is still a ZKPoK, just for another type of witness. You're right, but this trick is inevitable: if a prover can provide a proof, and the language is not trivial,
the prover necessarily knows something special (otherwise, anybody can conduct such proofs for himself, and language becomes trivial! ).
And this special thing is a witness! But, this could be another type of witness,
not that one which you initially supposed. This is a core idea of the trick.

WARNING: this is an improvisation and I'm not 100% sure in this, so please wait for endorsement of other people.

Comment: How would you handle "know a witness" part? Did you mean something that avoids extractor algorithm?

Comment: @VadymFedyukovych no, I mean only based on knowledge extractor definition.

Comment: @VadymFedyukovych Your question is how to construct such extractor for this protocol for $L_1$ ? It's very simple, just the same way as for regular Schnorr: we're tricking the prover use the same commitment twice (by rewinding it). So for $L_1$ such witness-extractor exists. But my idea that for $L_2$ no extractor exists. So for $L_2$ this protocol is only a proof system, not proof of knowledge.

Comment: Please consider to double-check your $L_2$ language definition, "$y_2 = $" part.

Comment: @VadymFedyukovych Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice question, and I don't know any natural examples of interactive zero-knowledge proof systems which are not proofs of knowledge, although they are bound to exist. The (rewinding based) proofs I recall ensure soundness in a way which allows extraction.
That being said, for the non-interactive setting, the situation is quite different, and there are several examples which are *not known* (and very unlikely) to be extractable under standard assumptions (i.e. not using knowledge of exponents or the like).

The best example (although not ZK proofs) are hash proof systems/smooth projective hash functions which are used in the Cramer--Shoup IND-CCA secure construction.
There is no knowledge involved.
From this, Kiltz--Wee construct a (quasi-adaptive) NIZK.
These are for special languages though and not *proofs*, i.e. not unconditionally sound.

An example NIZK *arguments* for all of NP are Groth--Sahai proofs.
Perfect zero-knowledge cannot be extractable in the non-interactive setting.
There is also a non-interactive witness-indistinguishable NIWI version of Groth--Sahai proofs,
which is weaker than NIZK, but does not need a CRS.
(NIWI only guarantees that you cannot distinguish two (valid) witnesses $w, w'$ of a statement, but may otherwise learn information about $w$.)
They are not extractable.
Similarly, the Feige--Lapidot--Shamir [FLS] NIWI is not extractable (but needs the hidden bits model).

Non-extractable NIZK or NIWI, can be (stupidly) converted to interactive non-extractable ZK proofs:
First send an perfectly binding commitment to the NIWI proof,
and then prove in zero-knowledge that a NIWI verifier would accept.
Alternatively, use MPC to construct the CRS.

If you allow *arguments*, i.e. computational soundness, using the OR-trick from FLS gives you a more natural construction from NIWI:

1. V sends y = OWF(s)
2. P sends d = Com(0) and Com(NIWI: $x \in L \lor (d = Com(s) \land y = OWF(s))$)
3. V reveals s
4. P reveals NIWI
5. V accepts if NIWI verifies

Not formally proven, but plausible:
By hardness of the OWF, and binding of Com, cheating for P is computationally hard.
By hiding of Com, a simulator can rewind from step 3 to 2, and commit to the preimage s in d, and prove the OR-branch, instead of $x \in L$.