# Definition of soundness (a different approach) in "Witness Indistinguishable and Witness Hiding Protocols"

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, indistinguishability

In any other context where I encountered the concept of soundness it was very simple: if the input does not belong to the language then the protocol fails or fails with great probability.

But in the paper [Witness Indistinguishable and Witness Hiding Protocols](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/voting/papers/FeigeShamir-WitnessHidingAndWitnessIndistinguishableProtocols.pdf) there is an interaction between a prover $P$ (with a set of valid witnesses $w(x)$), a verifier $V$ and an input $x$ and the definition of soundness is:
$\exists M\ \forall P'\ \forall x\ \forall w'$,
$$ P[V_{P'(x, w')}(x) accepts] < P[M(x, w'; P') \in w(x)] + negligible $$
Where the probability is over the random tapes of $V$, $P'$ and $M$. $M$ uses $P'$ as a blackbox.

I just can not grasp this, can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

The soundness definition that you are familiar with is the normal soundness definition of proof systems. The soundness definition in this paper is a definition of soundness for "proofs of knowledge", i.e., the goal of the prover is not only to convince the verifier that the statement is true but also that it *knows* a witness. This can be a much stronger requirement.

Now, there are two main aspects in which this differs to the notion you're familiar with. The first aspect is related to this question: How can we formalize that the prover "knows" a witness? The short answer in informal words is: if there's a witness in the prover, then there must be some way to get it out of the prover. This extraction process is the job of the *knowledge extractor* $M$ in the definition you found. The knowledge extractor $M$ is given black-box access to $P$ in order to extract the witness. I could expand on this concept but I believe there are a lot of very good resources with different levels of rigor that elaborate specifically on this point [[1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68786/12020),[2](https://crypto.stanford.edu/cs355/19sp/lec5.pdf),[3](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2017/01/21/zero-knowledge-proofs-an-illustrated-primer-part-2/),[4](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.55.6223&rep=rep1&type=pdf)] because this is often a source of confusion for newcomers.

The second difference is that this definition relates the accepting probability of $P$ with the probability that $M$ extracts. In other words, whenever $P$ convinces the verifier, then $M$ should be able to extract a witness (with a negligible error). An alternative (but flawed) definition which is closer to the definition you're aware of would require that if $P$ convinces with non-negligible probability, then $M$ can extract successfully.* Variants of this definition have indeed been used early but they're too weak for what we typically need, as Bellare and Goldreich [[4](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.55.6223&rep=rep1&type=pdf)] explain in an entire paper that I very much recommend for a deeper understanding. In Appendix A, they explain why the definition you found is better than the flawed definition but still not optimal.

A final remark is that the paper you've found is already pretty old. These were the first days of zero-knowledge when the community was still in the process of finding good definitions for zero-knowledge proof systems, which can be nicely seen from the paper by Bellare and Goldreich [[4](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.55.6223&rep=rep1&type=pdf)]. The definitions in newer works may be clearer.

*Note that the condition "if the statement is in the language" would obviously be too weak: just because the statement is in the language does not mean that some $P$ (which could be just a dummy machine outputting only zeros) knows a witness.